# How to publish private apps from google play console for customers, who wants to distribute it using MDM?

Tags: android, google-play-services, apk, mdm, google-play-console

I want to distribute my app through google private store to my customers , who want to distribute it using their MDM.

Can I use my developer account and distribute it to the organization using their organization ID ? or
Should I use the publishing API and build a custom APK ? When I use this publishing API should I make changes in the application ? How is it done ?

Can anyone help me with suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your developer account to privately distribute an app to a 3rd party organization. To do so:

1. Ask the organization for their organization ID
2. Add this ID to your app in **Pricing & Distribution > User programs > Managed Google Play**

More info on [Publish private apps from the Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139).

You don't need to create a custom APK or to use the publishing API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Fred. Can I ask one more thing ? In which case should I use this publishing API ?

Comment: This APK can be distributed only to 20 organisation , should I rename the same apk and upload it again if I want to distribute it to 21st customer ?

Comment: If you are thinking publishing your app to more than 20 organizations you should probably consider publishing your app publicly and implement a licensing system to restrict to your customers. Private app publishing is restricted to 20 organizations. 
And you can use the publishing API if you want to perform changes programmatically, typically when you want to make changes many times or to many apps.

Comment: @ fred,  So If I have, more than 20 customers. I can have my own licensing in the app and upload it to the public store. I guess it's clear. thanks for the help